# 3d line graph with javascript

Tags: javascript, graph, 3d, linechart, linegraph

I want to plot a 3-d line graph having many data points. Each data point represent a (x,y,z) combination. Does anyone know about any javascript library that can plot these points in 3-d plane?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043260

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [z3d.js](http://nathanepstein.github.io/jekyll/update/2015/01/11/z3d.html), it is easy to use. For more complex graphs, you may consider [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) .
Here is a similar question about [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) : 
[3 dimension (X, Y and Z) graph using D3.js ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043260/3-dimension-x-y-and-z-graph-using-d3-js)