# Javascript visualization package for multidimentional bar chart

Tags: javascript, charts, visualization, vis.js

I am looking for an open source visualization package to create a 3d bar chart similar to the one I have created in excel (see image below). I have tried vis.js, but there was no way I could tell to format the 'walls' to show gridlines and a background color. If this is possible in vis.js I could do that as well, but I didnt see anything in the documentation.

The features I need are:

1. Gridlines for 'walls'
2. background color options for 'walls'
3. Free movement/rotation
4. Ability to change individual bar color based on some logic
5. Ability to export image to pdf, etc..

Ideal Chart (excel):

[image: 3D Bar Chart]

Best I could do with vis.js:
[image]

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: With plotly I was able to get all the features I needed, however it was in their surface plot. (https://plot.ly/javascript/3d-surface-plots/#topographical-3d-surface-plot) Because these are discrete values, I need them showing as bars. It even added a hover feature to see each point. If only I could get it showing bars.

Comment: I see someone gave my question a downvote. If you believe that my question shows no research effort, is unclear of not useful please explain and I can clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look, HighChart has great features, you can use the non-commercial version.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/oscjara/4mjp7egw/
```

here is the library

```
jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/3d/skewed-labels/
```