# Is it possible to use date ranges as individual date items on time scale in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a chart like the one below but I am missing one crucial element. My current time scale is a standard one (1st picture) but I need to convert it to the time scale visible in 2nd picture. Is this even possible in D3? I am using D3.js V3.

[image]

[image: multi line chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know D3 doesn't include any functionality to rollup custom time intervals on the fly, but it seems like you could do this pretty simply with some basic javascript...

```js
    var data = [
            {date: new Date(2016, 11, 10), value: 1},
            {date: new Date(2016, 11, 11), value: 2},
            {date: new Date(2016, 11, 12), value: 3},
            {date: new Date(2016, 11, 13), value: 3},
            {date: new Date(2016, 11, 14), value: 2},
            {date: new Date(2016, 11, 15), value: 3},
            {date: new Date(2016, 11, 16), value: 5},
            {date: new Date(2016, 11, 16), value: 4},
            {date: new Date(2016, 11, 17), value: 2},
            {date: new Date(2016, 11, 19), value: 3},
            {date: new Date(2016, 11, 20), value: 1},
            {date: new Date(2016, 11, 21), value: 3}
        ];

    rollup(data, 3);

    function rollup(data, days) {
        var min = data.reduce(function(a, b) {if (b.date < a) return b.date; return a;}, new Date(3000, 1, 1)),
            max = data.reduce(function(a, b) {if (b.date > a) return b.date; return a;}, new Date(1000, 1, 1)),
            output = [];
        for (var day = min; day < max; day.setDate(day.getDate() + days)) {
            var end = new Date(day);
            end.setDate(end.getDate() + days);
            var working = data.filter(function(a) {return (a.date >= day && a.date < end);}),
                value = working.reduce(function(a, b) {return a + b.value;}, 0);
            output.push({date: day.toString() + ' - ' + end.toString(), value: value});
        }
        console.log(output);
        return output;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code sample, I may have an idea how to do it. I don't need to combine the values - they are already coming correct from the server, but I need to combine the date they are assigned to with the next one, similar to what you did in the script. I suppose I will then need to use d3 `axis.tickValues` function https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Axes.md#tickValues to display them.

Comment: I see you are using `reduce` to obtain `min` and `max` values in rollup function. This can be done with `d3.extent`: `x.domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.date));`

Comment: Yes, so the way I'd accomplish the tickValues is to use an ordinal scale along the x axis by your categories like [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125559/multi-line-ordinal-d3-chart). Agreed on `d3.extent` I have a preference for using prototype functions but this is probably better.

Comment: So you wouldn't use `tickValues` for the time scale?

Comment: [d3.scaleTime](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scaleTime) is great for a time series, but once you start doing these aggregations [d3.scaleOrdinal](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scaleOrdinal) will be simpler to implement because you can set your `x` scale to the label you want to appear on the axis `var x = d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(data.map(function(d) {return d.label;}))` then you can get the axis setup very simply by just calling d3.axisBottom directly `.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")").call(d3.axisBottom(x))`